# Can I turn a awt image into a gwt image?

Tags: java, image, gwt, awt, transform

Is there a way to turn a AWT Image into a GWT image?
On the server-side, i transformed a byte array into an image:

```
public Image getImageData(byte[] imageByteArray)
{
     String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(imageByteArray);
     base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + base64;
     byte[] byteArray = base64.getBytes();
     //byte[] byteArray = BASE64Decoder.decode(imageByteArray);
     Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byteArray);
     image = createNewImage(image);
     return image;
}

private Image createNewImage(Image image)
{
    try
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(l);
        tracker.addImage(image, 0);
        tracker.waitForAll();
        return image;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now im sending it to client-side via RPC and i wanna ad it to my UiBinder class. But it wants a GWT Image and

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byteArray)
```

needs AWT image.

Comment: why do not you want to send base64 string to client?

Comment: doenst work. dunno why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT doesn't support `java.awt.anything`.  You have to use the `GWT Image class`.

```
GWT != Java
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/wBryd0GbBT8

Comment: sooo can I somehow do this Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byteArray); and get a gwt image?

Comment: someone said i may have to decode the byte[] and i have to use the media tracker. but that one also needs awt image...

Comment: tried this: public Image getImageData(byte[] imageByteArray)
    {
        String base64 = com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils.toBase64(imageByteArray);
        base64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64; 
        Image image = new Image(base64);
        return image;
    }

Comment: Base64Utils from GWT's source does not use the standard MIME characters when encoding data to Base64.

Comment: And go through this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/CWwkYQjQ0q4

Comment: Cheers .. welcome :)Please upvote and mark it as answer if its useful.

Comment: do you know how i could display that image on a button now? cause for setbackgroundimage, i need a url. could i safe the image temporarly and use the url somehow?

Comment: Sorry ,Really know idea about that .